# Рандомнная позиция элемента на странице javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть html разметка:

```
<div class="map-location"></div>
```

Есть css стиль для него:

```
.map-location {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 35%;
}
```

Задача:

Я хочу убрать с `css` `top` и `left` и блоку map-location присвоить атрибут `style` и в нем `top` и `left` задавать с рандомными значениями от 0 до 100.

Можно ли такое реализовать на JS? Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Можно. Копайте в сторону `Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rndBtn = document.querySelector('#rndBtn');
rndBtn.addEventListener('click', randomize, false )

function randomize(e) {
  const max = 100;
  loc = document.querySelector('.map-location');
  loc.style.top =  `${Math.floor(Math.random()*(max + 1))}%`
  loc.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random()*max + 1)}%`
}
```

```css
.map-location {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 35%;
}
button{
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Random point</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="map-location">*</div>
  <button id="rndBtn">Random</button>
</body>
</html>
```